# dotnetCore (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177) - build warnings as errors - how?

Tags: .net-core

Does anyone know which switch (in the project.json?) to use to ensure that a dotNetCore build that includes a warning in the output is marked as failed?

Answer (score 4):

I did find [warningsaserrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#warningsaserrors) in the dotnet reference.